# Is there a way in win32 c++ to open a file with the permissions of another user?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I know that there is a method to create process as user

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682429%28v=vs.85%29.aspx.

What I am looking for is kind of the same thing except for having to do with files to open a file as a different user with their permissions.
Is there a way to do this with the openfilebyid function documented here?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365432%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Are there also any examples on how to successfully do this?

Comment: OpenFileById doesn't do what you are asking for. It opens a file, based on a `FILE_ID_DESCRIPTOR`, which isn't anything to do with user's. You probably do need a second process running as that user to achieve that.

Comment: It's not clear what OpenFileById has to do with this. You can use LogonUser to get a token for the other user, then impersonate that user, then open the file while impersonating.

Comment: Look up ImpersonateLoggedOnUser in MSDN.

Comment: I guess I should have put more information into the question than I already did.  The program I am trying to write would need to access multiple files from multiple users at the same time.  I have put some thought into opening up a new process to access the file, but that seems like a lot of overhead for something that should be relatively simple.

Comment: @RustyWeber: you have to impersonate the desired user before opening the file.  It will be opened using whatever user is currently associated with the calling thread.

Comment: The problem is, what happens when I want to impersonate multiple users opening different files in different threads?

Comment: Impersonation affects only the current thread.  So you can impersonate different users on different threads at the same time without any difficulty.

Comment: Also, the impersonation is only needed when opening the file.  Once you've got a handle to the file, you don't need to impersonate in order to use the handle to read or write.

Comment: Are you 100% positive? I thought it affected the entire process.

Comment: Read the docs - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378612(v=vs.85).aspx - it says "calling thread".